# Is it possible to customize the AWS Chatbot Message on CodePipeline Fail?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-chatbot

We are currently switching from Travis to CodeBuild/CodePipeline.

Travis has a built in functionality for slack where we can send the commit hash, author name, commit message etc.

I have the AWS Chatbot set up to send a message to slack during a Code Pipeline event failure but the message doesn't include any details, ideally I'd like to tag a user on slack as well but at the very least I'd like the author name / commit hash.

I don't see any settings for the AWS Chatbot, I was thinking I could create a SNS Topic that CodeBuild would notify that would then hit a lambda function that would use Slack web hooks to send a message to a channel, but I'm unsure if I'd be able to send identifying information this way either.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at using codebuild notifications. It can be configured to send a useful payload to lambda to trigger Slack. Unfortunately with AWS Chatbot, it's limited on customization at the expense of setting something up quickly. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-build-notifications.html